# Math.random number of random bits

Tags: javascript, random, cross-browser

Is there any requirement on how many random bits `Math.random` is supposed to produce? I did some tests on Chrome and Firefox's implementations, converting the results to hex to examine the bits, and Firefox 27.0.1 gives results like

```
0x1.de619579d56f3p-1
0x1.ef1ada9306decp-2
0x1.df3b75e208ce6p-1
```

whereas Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m gives

```
0x1.1190f39c00000p-2
0x1.b959e3b600000p-1
0x1.90f614b400000p-2
```

which is godawful in comparison. It appears to be a 32-bit result, whereas Firefox's values seem to use 53 random bits.

Comment: I have never seen numbers being represented that way. Is that just the hex representation of the decimal number?

Comment: @thefourtheye: See the [specification of the format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex). I used Python (didn't see a native Javascript tool for the conversion), but the same format is also used in C and Java. The part between the `x` and the `p` is a hexadecimal number, and the part after the `p` is a decimal representing a power of two to multiply it by.

Comment: Oh, thanks man. But the [`Math.random()`'s spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.14) doesn't say anything about it. So, it actually depends on the implemenetation I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14

> 15.8.2.14 random ( )
>
> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no arguments.

Seems to be all the spec says.

Answer (score 1):

https://v8.dev/blog/math-random says Chrome 49 uses a random number generator called "xorshift128+" and I think Firefox does too.  This generates 64-bit results (converted to floats, which I think means 53 bits of precission) with a period of 2^128-1.

https://lwn.net/Articles/666407/ has some more history of the browsers' RNGs.